# How to know a URL comes from a browser's address bar or a ajax call?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, web

I have a URL request below:

```
https://myapp.com/funnyproject/tools/getLayers.ashx?search=true
```

And I can call it by directly entering it in the address bar or, it can be done via an ajax request from the client:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "tools/getLayers.ashx?search=true",
    headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

So the question here is how I can know where it comes from?
I tried with `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer` property, but it's not helpful.
Any advice, please!

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can check for the presence of the request header `X-Requested-With` for ajax request. but a user if decides, can remove that header before sending request. Look into [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) if you concerned with other sites sending requests to your site.

Comment: I am trying to reject a direct access from the address bar to a handler (ashx). My web app only allows a call from Ajax. And to do that, I need to detect which one comes from the address bar and which one comes from Ajax.

Comment: Such a restriction is not actually realistically possible. But you can keep honest people honest with above header check.

Comment: You should understand the concept of user agent. Chrome and such browsers are one category of user agents, there are headless, command line, and numerous other types of user agents which can talk http(s) and they can send request identical to the one other types of user agent sends because they all talk same protocol and that is all that matters to your server. Don't waste your time with unrealistic restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent user to make ajax call which will look like browser's one. But for default call, to identify calls made from, you can use header User-agent.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

There you can get not only browser but also the Type and Version of it, also OS and some other information.

`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36`